# Remove empty rows and columns in DataTable using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I have dataset. A DataTable inside it contains empty rows and columns.I have to delete those are all. Let me know how can i do this.

Comment: `DataSet` cannot contain rows and columns, you mean `DataTable` within a `DataSet`, right?

Comment: Yes, Data Table with in data set.sorry for my mistake

Comment: @KaivthaBindela, I am still confused, Do you want to remove datatables with 0 rows from your dataset ? or you want to remove empty DataRows from a particular table inside the dataset ?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (Dataset mydatasetcopy = new Dataset())
{
    mydatasetcopy.Tables.AddRange(mydataset.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Where(dt => 
    dt.Rows.Count > 0).ToArray());

    mydataset = mydatasetcopy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
for (int h = 0; h < Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; h++)
{
    if(Ds.Tables[0].Rows[h].IsNull(0)==true)
    {
        Ds.Tables[0].Rows[h].Delete();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

or this

```
String valuesarr = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    List<object> lst = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.ToList();
    foreach (Object s in lst)
    {
        valuesarr += s.ToString();
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(valuesarr))  
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
 }
```

Comment: please don't use `==true` in an if clause...